# Flutter background of unsafe area in SafeArea widget.

Tags: dart, flutter

When I provide the `SafeArea` to a Widget, then it gets some margin from the notches and home button (horizontal line in iPhone X +). How can I change the background of the unsafe area ? (The margin portion)?

Comment: there is a very good widget to handle this: https://pub.dev/packages/colorful_safe_area . it is not mine btw

Answer (score 196, accepted):

Wrap your `SafeArea` into a widget that adds a background:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: SafeArea(...),
),
```

Comment: How would you make only the area padded by the SafeArea that color? Instead of all child content?

Comment: @MisterJimson give a background color to the child as well to eliminate it

Comment: For some reason, this color occludes system icons on the system statusbar completely with my landscape app. Actually, with or without the colonization, I lose the system icons. I wonder if this is a limitation of SafeArea.

Answer (score 17):

Another way to do it.

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

Scaffold(
  body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
    value: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
      statusBarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
    ),
    child: SafeArea(
      child: Container(...),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: This helps with adjusting the safe areas text and icon colors

Answer (score 7):

Following on from Rémi Rousselet's answer...

In my case, I created a new widget called `ColoredSafeArea`:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ColoredSafeArea extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final Color? color;

  const ColoredSafeArea({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    this.color,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: color ?? Theme.of(context).appBarTheme.backgroundColor,
      child: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.background,
          child: child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And use this in place of `SafeArea` in my `Scaffold`. I have it set up to use the current AppBar colour from my theme, by default. But you can use whatever works for you, of course.

Basically, this widget will change the SafeArea colour without affecting your app background colour, due to the `Container` within, which takes the background colour from the current theme's `colorScheme`. The advantage of this is that the background colour will work with any dark or light themes you have set up.

Answer (score 7):

This is probably the easiest way to accomplish this:

```
const Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Text(
          "White scaffold background that also applies to status bar",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Basically use `SafeArea` as a child of `Scaffold` and set the scaffold's background color to whatever you want or use `ThemeData` to set it globally using the `scaffoldBackgroundColor` prop

Answer (score 1):

I have combined both the above answers to achieve

1. the system theme set (dark/light)
2. the color/gradient of unsafe area

The code I've used is

```
var brightness = SchedulerBinding.instance.window.platformBrightness;
bool isDarkModeOn = brightness == Brightness.dark;

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: AnnotatedRegion<SystemUiOverlayStyle>(
        value: isDarkModeOn
            ? SystemUiOverlayStyle.dark.copyWith(
                statusBarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              )
            : SystemUiOverlayStyle.light.copyWith(
                statusBarColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
              ),
        child: Container(
          decoration: getScreenGradient(),
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Stack(
                  children: [
                    getBackgroundImage(),
                    getBody(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```